# how to remove id of div in url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having in an url the id of a div (#latest) like this at the end:

```
http://example.com/discussion/64/moderators-only#latest
http://example.com/discussion/32/bugs#latest
// and so on...
```

How can i remove the #latest in all these url's with htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Anything after the `#` is a URL fragment that the browser never even sends to the server. So the only thing the webserver sees is: `http://example.com/discussion/64/moderators-only`. So nothing in the htaccess or even in the apache config can do anything about those fragments.

You'll need to employ some sort of javascript or client-side solution if you want to remove it. But a better question is, do you need this in order to display the content correctly? If so, then how do you expect to display the content if this is gone?

Comment: Well, i use this for Vanilla forum. Normally, when hit a topic, it goes immediately to the last comment of the topic. I disabled this function with this line: $Configuration['Vanilla']['Comments']['AutoOffset'] = FALSE; Now it shows the topic at the very first comment, but in the url is still #latest. So i was wondering how to hide this from the url because it has no function anymore

Comment: @nuetmaessen I'm not familiar with that software, but whatever the code is that is generating those links needs to be fixed. Otherwise, you can write some javascript to get rid of it

Comment: Much appreciated for the advise!